# scaling canvas size dynamically to fit image fabric.js

Tags: image, canvas, resize, size, fabricjs

I am developing small application using fabric.js in which i have to load image from system on canvas & dynamically canvas size should change to fit the image. can anyone help me out?

```
function main() {

    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas');

    // loading image on canvas
    document.getElementById('uploadedImg').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = event.target.result;

            imgObj.onload = function () {

                // start fabricJS stuff
                image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                image.set({

                    centeredRotation: true,
                    centeredScaling: true,
                });

                canvas.add(image);
            };

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    };
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code, then one will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Inside this function

```
 imgObj.onload = function () {

                // start fabricJS stuff
                image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                image.set({

                    centeredRotation: true,
                    centeredScaling: true,
                });

                canvas.add(image);
            };
```

You can get image height and width using **imgObj.width** and **imgObj.height**

and then set 
canvas dimension like this

```
canvas.setHeight(imgObj.height);
canvas.setWidth(imgObj.width);
```

Like this

```
imgObj.onload = function () {

 canvas.setHeight(imgObj.height);
canvas.setWidth(imgObj.width);
                // start fabricJS stuff
                image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                image.set({

                    centeredRotation: true,
                    centeredScaling: true,
                });

                canvas.add(image);
            };
```